# Enable codeium sugestions inside vscode's powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

How to enablesugestions for powershell inside vscode?

[image]

Right now, the much I can do is to copy the sugested text and to press right-click to insert it. But I'd like to do it at once by pressing some shortcut.

Comment: That looks like PowerShell's own command predictor - you can complete the suggestion by pressing right-arrow

Comment: That is not working for me. Right arrow causes paste action.